# Is it possible to replace the UIView behind a popover (or a modal view) based on the popover actions?

Tags: ios, uipopover

Need to implement a popover (or a modal view), and based on selection in the popover, may go to another view once the popover is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Add delegate to popover, and trigger an action after the select. Then you can do whatever you want based on results of popover. If you need some more help please provide some code.

I will try to help you without your code:

Create protocol for the method you want to trigger:

```
@protocol someMethodDelegate
- (void)functionYouWantToTrigger;
@end
```

In your view controller(MyViewController) from which you call your popover .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController<someMethodDelegate>
```

In your .m file for MyViewController you have declaration like:

```
MyPopOver *popover = [[MyPopOver alloc] init];
popover.delegate = self;
```

Later on, in your .m file:

```
- (void)functionYouWantToTrigger{
    //do some wild things here
}
```

And lastely, in your popover on some event:

```
[self.deleagate functionYouWantToTrigger];
```

You can expend this method with attributes as you wish.